# How to create "averaged values" table in Excel using primary keys?

Tags: excel, primary-key

I have a huge Excel table that looks like this :

[image]

The names of the states are the **primary keys**. How can I create a new table that would show average prices across the states? It should contain 51 rows and look like this:

[image]

Comment: Create a pivot table on the data, and select `Average` as the aggregation function for the data columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Subtotal feature. Select all the cells that contain data and open the Subtotal dialog box (Data menu, Subtotals command).

For information [Calculating subtotals and working with levels in Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/calculating-subtotals-and-working-with-levels-in-excel-HA001109798.aspx)